# Fulltext search with lucene

Tags: java, lucene, full-text-search, jcr, jackrabbit-oak

I have recently been working on a Java JCR project with Jackrabbit Oak.
I am trying to implement fulltext search capabilities via lucene index, but I am having problems.

This is the lucene index I created:

```
/oak:index/lucene
  - jcr:primaryType = "oak:QueryIndexDefinition"
  - type = "lucene"
  - compatVersion = 2
  - async = "async"
  + indexRules
    - jcr:primaryType = "nt:unstructured"
    + nt:base
      + properties
        - jcr:primaryType = "nt:unstructured"
        + jcr:content
          - name = "jcr:content"
          - type = "String"
          - propertyIndex = false
          - analyzed = true
```

This is the Node I would like to search for

```
Node[NodeDelegate{tree=/home/test.txt: {
    jcr:primaryType = nt:unstructured,
    jcr:uuid = 1aa8c2a2-c06c-49f0-892d-96d40d78921b,
    jcr:versionHistory = f1c33e1b-2d97-4e12-8fc0-cdb6881d08b8,
    jcr:predecessors = [],
    jcr:isCheckedOut = false,
    jcr:mixinTypes = [mix:versionable],
    jcr:baseVersion = 26d68547-e60a-44e5-a8e6-1aa04d1012d1,
    jcr:content = {
        jcr:primaryType = nt:resource,
        jcr:uuid = fc2b91a3-9d6e-41a2-bc45-62945081c2db,
        jcr:lastModifiedBy = admin,
        jcr:data = {9 bytes},
        jcr:mimeType = log, 
        cr:lastModified = 2021-03-09T14:33:41.933+01:00
    }
}}]
```

The content (jcr:data) of file test.txt is:

```
test test
```

This is the query I use for the search

```
SELECT * FROM [nt:base] AS node WHERE CONTAINS([nt:base], 'test')
```

However, when I execute it, I don't get any results.
Why?